# Overwrite ajaxComplete for particular ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery

My application has a ajaxComplete() which is defined in a  generic .js file loaded in every view page. How can I overwrite this or better still avoid running it for specific $.ajax() call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `global: false` in your `$.ajax` call.

From [the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Whether to trigger global Ajax event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being triggered.

Your call will look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/',
    data: data,
    global: false,
    success: function() {

    }/* etc... */
});
```